# Hover state sticks when leaving the page- ignores mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseleave, mouseenter

I'm using some pretty standard JavaScript/jQuery to handle hovering elements, image swaps, sliding divs, animations, etc., it does not matter.  If/when clicking an "hoverable" linked element takes you to a new page, the **mouseenter** hover state always sticks.

For example, if you hover over something and click it (links to another page), then use the back button to return to the page, the **mouseenter** state on the element you clicked, is stuck even though your mouse is no longer over the element.

You have to either reload the page or re-hover the element to reset everything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mySelector').each(function () {
        $(this).hover(enter, leave);
    });

    function enter(event) { 
        // mouseenter stuff
    };
    function leave(event) { 
        // mouseleave stuff
    };
});
```

I seem to remember reading about this several weeks ago and there was a very simple fix but I can no longer find that.

Is anyone familiar with a proper solution?

**Thank-you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply "re-setting" the hover effects by calling the **mouse leave** function with the window "unload"...

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    leave();
});
```

Whenever you leave the page by clicking the hovered element, the **mouseleave** function is called even though your mouse is still hovering over the element.  Hitting the browser's back button no longer takes you back to the page with a "stuck" hover effect.

**Problem solved.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.each` for this. Also, the functions should be outside `.ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mySelector').hover(enter, leave);
});

function enter(event) { 
    // mouseenter stuff
}

function leave(event) { 
    // mouseleave stuff
}
```

Edit: 
If your variables are local, you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.mySelector').hover(function(){
         // mouseenter stuff
     },
     function(){
         // mouseleave stuff
     });
});
```

Comment: I'm using "each" because there are multiple elements.

Comment: @Sparky672, even if there are multiple elements, you don't need `.each` in this case. jQuery will bind the hover event to all the elements with the `.mySelector` class.

Comment: Moving the functions outside totally breaks the hover.

Comment: @jSang, my apologies for an abridged example.  In my working code, I have a few other things going on in there requiring the "each".

Comment: @jSang, I see.  However, my functions are using local variables so it  breaks when I move the two enter & leave functions outside of the document.ready function.

Comment: Why don't you put the implementation inside the hover function without calling the enter and leave functions. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: @jSang, this is all besides the original point.  My code is functioning the same... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5NKVp/1/) and does not have any affect on the original problem.

Comment: @jSang, **you wrote**: _"Why don't you put the implementation inside the hover function without calling the enter and leave functions. I think that will solve your problem."_   No, I just tried that too... the original reported problem is still there.  We keep rearranging the deck chairs and the code keeps functioning as it always has.

Comment: @jSang-  Thanks for all your help.  I ended up solving the problem by simply calling the mouse **"leave()"** function on page **unload**.